# C Arrays - used / unused array values

Tags: c, arrays, sprite

I am creating a 'Space invaders' style game where I need to limit my number of bullets to 100. I believe my best option is to Devise some way to indicate if a bullet is "in use" or "available". 
When user presses "Launch missile" key, scan the array to find an available bullet.
If there are no available bullets, do nothing.
If there is an available bullet, launch the bullet found, and make it be "in use".
When the bullet flies off the screen, or when it hits a diamond, make it be "available".

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Assuming you already use some sort of struct for each bullet (for its coordinates, etc.), just add another member to use as an in-use flag... or use an otherwise invalid value for one of the other fields to indicate an unused bullet.

Comment: @Dmitri I'm a bit confused with how to implement the array, This is what I've tried so far [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1Law3IdbnVqRW1JNmhOM0NTOVk)

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far

Comment: Looks like `sprite_t` has an `is_visible` member you could use... If you can assume invisible bullets are unused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw your Code, u have a bullet array all you need is a lastUsedIndex for the last used bullet. Initialize this with the last bullet index (Max bullet -1). If the bullet hits, do nothing. If it misses "hide" the bullet and decrement d index. If the index hits -1 Game over.

Comment: Still having trouble working out how to do this...Could you do an example by any chance? <3